# How to PWM-drive a N-channel non-logic level power MOSFET with a 3.3V signal?

Tags: mosfet, zener, logic-level, gate-driving

**Follow-up of [Using IR21531 as a simple 1 channel gate driver](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/206623/using-ir21531-as-a-simple-1-channel-gate-driver/206636#206636)**

After doing the above question (I'm very sorry, beacuse my question seems a [XY](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) one), I'll try to explain better what I <s>believe that I</s> want (current circuit below):

I'm doing a space-saving design for a LED driver. On it, I only have a 78V PSU and a 3.3V PSU.

The module drive with PWM a LED strip, but the control signal will be of 3.3V and the MOSFET needs more than 10V to trigger. How can I get let's say 15V for driving the gate?

I've seen some vague words on some electronics forums saying that I could use a zener diode. How could I use the zener diode?

I'm open to suggestions. Also I could use a optoisolated transistor along with the zener.

---

**Update:** The below circuit seems to be well done, but with more than 50% of PWM duty cycle, the lamp starts blinking and fading as if it have a capacitor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV5cMA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: That circuit won't work (more later) but what are the LEDs i.e. what spec (spec.pdf data sheet and no links to ebay etc.) are they and, are you aware that forcing a fixed voltage across 1 or more LEDs in series is a recipe for disaster unless there is a current limiting mechanism.

Comment: @Andyaka: The **V1** supply is a constant current power supply at 300mA

Comment: Then don't confuse folk by showing it as a constant voltage. Nobody here is a mind reader.

Comment: @Andyaka: What should be? http://i.stack.imgur.com/t3iai.png

Comment: The current source is back to front but I'd just add a note saying it's current limited to 300 mA.

Comment: @Andyaka: Done!

Answer (score 2):

This answer was made before the OP decided to scrap his original circuit (following what I'd said) thus rendering part of my answer obsolete. The OP should consider that evolving his questions following advice in answers is problematic. Regards the new circuit drawn, it is full of mistakes and won't work effectively when those mistakes are corrected. Note to the OP - if you persist in evolving your question, don't expect any more help from me. Neither should you take it on yourself to edit my answer.

**Original answer: -**

Firstly, if the power supply can produce 200V then the IRF630 is a terrible choice - it's maximum voltage rating is only 200V and you need clearance - I'd go for a MOSFET with 300V ratings.

Secondly, the solution is best addressed by putting the MOSFET at the bottom of the chain of LEDs. Now its source connects to ground and driving from a 3V3 signal is easy except that the IRF630 won't be great at turning on with a 3V3 signal. It might work but, given its inadequate voltage rating I'd look for a better device. Here's what I'm thinking: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fboBIX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So try looking at Fairchild (for example) to find a suitable MOSFET

Comment: I've removed the 200V part because it was for simplifying, it works at 78V.

Comment: When I switch the gate directly at 3.3V, the leds are dimming well, but with a very low brightness.

Comment: Could you kindly read the update of my question?

Comment: The zener and opto transistor are backwards. When that is fixed the mosfet will overheat. I think you need to start thinking about not evolving this question any more.

Comment: @Andy:  What does "o/c" mean?  Also, which mosfet would you use for M1?

Comment: @Andyaka: Why the mosfet will overheat?

Comment: @Helio in your circuit, the highest gate voltage is when it is tied to the drain and if you need 10V across gate and source to deliver 300 mA to the load then the source **MUST** be 10V below the gate (and drain). Therefore the drain-source voltage is 10 volts and the drain current is 0.3 amps therefore the power dissipated is 3 watts. You can use a heatsink of course but aren't you looking for a space saving design. Do you need to use an opto-coupler BTW?

Comment: @Andyaka: I can remove the opto-coupler. I'm very sorry, but I'm very confused (and I fear that I'm also confusing you). I tried to use the zener to limit the gate voltage to 15V and avoid burning the optocoupler (because its max. voltage is 70V and at 78V it breaks). My only aim is to dim the leds using PWM. I'm facing a **very** strange problem, when I use the optocoupler, the LED strip starts blinking and fading on power off (as if a capacitor were in series with the strip).

Comment: @Andyaka: Also if you want I can interrupt the low side instead of the high side.

Comment: The circuit I have shown is the circuit you should be using but you may need to use a mosfet that can switch on witha 3v3 drive level. Your opto circuit makes no sense and, if you wish to understand how mosfets work in common drain versus common source configurations you should ask a fresh question and I guarantee you'll get some good answers.

Comment: @Andyaka: I will not request you to enter in details about common drain/source configuration (by now). I only want to ask you why the strip starts blinking when I try to PWM the MOSFET gate.

Comment: @Andyaka: My current setup is this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ogis9.png

Comment: I'll need details of the power supply i.e. a data sheet. Ditto the LEDs. Also, are you sharing 0V with whatever is being used to create the 3V3 square wave? This isn't clear.

Comment: @Andyaka: I'm sharing 0V (I'm not as silly to leave it floating **;-)**. I doubt that I can get a datasheet for the PSU. Is a (extremely Chinese) cheap power supply (18W 300mA constant current).

Comment: If you short the mosfet drain to source) what happens with the LEDs.

Comment: @Andyaka: They power up.

Comment: @Andyaka: And when I touch Gate the MOSFET does strange things.

Comment: @Andyaka: And when I connect Gate with Drain, It turns ON.

Comment: @Andyaka: And when I connect Gate with Source, It turns OFF.

Comment: Maybe your mosfet is killed. Try a new one but, given you haven't specified the led I can't help much further. I know you have doubts but get a new fet and tell me what LEDs you are using.

Comment: You are using IRF630N, whose Vgs(th) may rise up to 4V. With a 3.3V gate voltage, the MOS may stay blocked. You should consider driving your gate with an higher voltage (max 20V)